Promote a QWidget to a QAxWidget using Qt Designer and PyQt5
I want to promote a QWidget to a QAxWidget. I want to avoid using QWebengineView to display a PDF file (I can't zoom it) so I decide to implement this solution instead (bottom solution): Solution
In there he coded the widget in the main window but I want to use Qt Designer to generate the .ui file. Following this solution solution using Qt Designer I can promote a QWidget to another class (as I understand promoting is subclassing a class) but I can't make the solution works for me. I have tried using QAxWidget and QAxContainer as header file but it's still not working. There is no doubt that I am not understanding promoting in Qt Designer.
This is my Qt Designer window:

This is my .ui file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Form</class>
 <widget class="QWidget" name="Form">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>993</width>
    <height>758</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Form</string>
  </property>
  <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
   <item>
    <widget class="pdfViewer" name="widget" native="true"/>
   </item>
  </layout>
 </widget>
 <customwidgets>
  <customwidget>
   <class>pdfViewer</class>
   <extends>QWidget</extends>
   <header location="global">QAxWidget</header>
   <container>1</container>
  </customwidget>
 </customwidgets>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>

and this is my .py module:
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(993, 758)
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(Form)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.widget = pdfViewer(Form)
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.widget)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
from QAxWidget import pdfViewer

The last line points an error: QAxWidget is not a package, is a class.
This is my mainwindow code:
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from view.container import Ui_Form
import sys
import os
import urllib.parse

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.widget.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.StrongFocus)
        self.widget.setControl("{8856F961-340A-11D0-A96B-00C04FD705A2}")

        pdf_path = r"C:\Users\isDev\Documents\ismael\respaldo\UrimareGUI\ReportLab\datasheet.pdf"
        uri = urllib.parse.urljoin('file:', urllib.request.pathname2url(pdf_path))

        self.widget.dynamicCall('Navigate(const QString&)', uri)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()

and this is the error I get when I run the test.py:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\isDev\OneDrive\Documents\PythonScripts\urimareApp\test.py", line 2, in <module>
    from view.container import Ui_Form
  File "C:\Users\isDev\OneDrive\Documents\PythonScripts\urimareApp\view\container.py", line 30, in <module>
    from QAxWidget import pdfViewer
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'QAxWidget'

I don't know how to promote the QWidget in Qt Designer

"It doesn't work" doesn't really help us, we need more: for instance, do you get any errors? Have you checked the output of your program (possibly by running it in a terminal/prompt, not just in the IDE)? And, yes, we need code, even if you use Designer. Specifically, an [mre] of this problem should include: the UI file (it's an XML file, just open it with a text editor), the main python script, and, if you implemented the promoted widget in another script, that code too. Please ensure that what you provide is both minimal (remove anything unrelated to the problem) and reproducible.

@musicamante ok, I will edit the post

@musicamante done it!

The error is clear: you're using the class name as the module. The "header" is where the class is defined, which in this specific case should be QAxContainer (or probably PyQt5.QAxContainer), while the class name is QAxWidget. Using pdfViewer is wrong, because there's no such thing declared anyway. I suggest you to search more about widget promotion (start from this and this) and consider that you're actually adding an existing Qt widget, so you don't need a custom script for the promotion, but the proper module/class names.

@musicamante I have already tried to use QAxWidget as the class name and Qt Designer shows me a popup window with: this class name already exist. That's why I was giving it the name of pdfViewer

@musicamante you said in the second link that it is important that the base class (in my case QWidget) must be compatible with QAxContainer... now araises another doubt: is it? how can I figure it out? maybe this is a main problem that will not let me to promote the QWidget?

If it already exists then it should be visible in the widget box list. All widgets inherit from QWidget at some level, since it's the base class for all widgets. You can always check the documentation of the selected class and look for the "Inherits from:" section in the docs header.

@musicamante I checked in the widget box list and it does not appear. Well, I guess I should take the long way and create the QAxWidget by coding. Thanks anyway

Check again with the filter, and ensure that all sub sections are expanded: that message should only appear for widgets that are already available, and they are normally listed there. Alternatively, look if the QAxWidget appears in the "Base class name" combo of the widget promotion dialog (but I doubt it). In any case, nothing prevents you to create your own subclass of QAxWidget: just follow my explanation linked above, inheriting from QAxWidget instead of QWidget and then add that subclass to the promotion. That would also be better, as you could automatically specialize it for your needs.

@musicamante I coud find in the QtDesigner the QAxWidgwt in the toolbar so what I was trying to achive was no sense. I used it instead and it works fine!! thanks
